# filtering a DataFrame based on rows being less than a percent of sum of any column

Tags: python, pandas

Here are my example data:

```
{'Rhesus': {('count', u'augCGP,transMap'): 6.0, ('count', u'augTM,transMap'): 11563.0, ('count', u'transMap'): 39930.0, ('count', u'augTM'): 5114.0, ('count', u'augCGP,augTM,augTMR,transMap'): 27.0, ('count', u'augCGP,augTMR'): 1.0, ('count', u'augTMR,transMap'): 145.0, ('count', u'augTMR'): 4217.0, ('count', u'augCGP,augTMR,transMap'): nan, ('count', u'augCGP,augTM,augTMR'): nan, ('count', u'augCGP'): 4239.0, ('count', u'augCGP,augTM,transMap'): 3.0, ('count', u'augTM,augTMR,transMap'): 6296.0, ('count', u'augTM,augTMR'): 3357.0}, 'Susie': {('count', u'augCGP,transMap'): 11.0, ('count', u'augTM,transMap'): 10821.0, ('count', u'transMap'): 41300.0, ('count', u'augTM'): 2894.0, ('count', u'augCGP,augTM,augTMR,transMap'): 43.0, ('count', u'augCGP,augTMR'): nan, ('count', u'augTMR,transMap'): 353.0, ('count', u'augTMR'): 5399.0, ('count', u'augCGP,augTMR,transMap'): 1.0, ('count', u'augCGP,augTM,augTMR'): 1.0, ('count', u'augCGP'): 2740.0, ('count', u'augCGP,augTM,transMap'): 2.0, ('count', u'augTM,augTMR,transMap'): 10196.0, ('count', u'augTM,augTMR'): 2789.0}, 'Clint': {('count', u'augCGP,transMap'): 16.0, ('count', u'augTM,transMap'): 17341.0, ('count', u'transMap'): 39284.0, ('count', u'augTM'): 2888.0, ('count', u'augCGP,augTM,augTMR,transMap'): 80.0, ('count', u'augCGP,augTMR'): 1.0, ('count', u'augTMR,transMap'): 144.0, ('count', u'augTMR'): 2881.0, ('count', u'augCGP,augTMR,transMap'): nan, ('count', u'augCGP,augTM,augTMR'): 1.0, ('count', u'augCGP'): 2338.0, ('count', u'augCGP,augTM,transMap'): 8.0, ('count', u'augTM,augTMR,transMap'): 8725.0, ('count', u'augTM,augTMR'): 1441.0}, 'Orangutan': {('count', u'augCGP,transMap'): 7.0, ('count', u'augTM,transMap'): 6568.0, ('count', u'transMap'): 46113.0, ('count', u'augTM'): 3656.0, ('count', u'augCGP,augTM,augTMR,transMap'): 17.0, ('count', u'augCGP,augTMR'): nan, ('count', u'augTMR,transMap'): 284.0, ('count', u'augTMR'): 5952.0, ('count', u'augCGP,augTMR,transMap'): 1.0, ('count', u'augCGP,augTM,augTMR'): 1.0, ('count', u'augCGP'): 5753.0, ('count', u'augCGP,augTM,transMap'): 3.0, ('count', u'augTM,augTMR,transMap'): 6567.0, ('count', u'augTM,augTMR'): 3520.0}, 'Gibbon': {('count', u'augCGP,transMap'): 5.0, ('count', u'augTM,transMap'): 6828.0, ('count', u'transMap'): 44285.0, ('count', u'augTM'): 4313.0, ('count', u'augCGP,augTM,augTMR,transMap'): 16.0, ('count', u'augCGP,augTMR'): nan, ('count', u'augTMR,transMap'): 187.0, ('count', u'augTMR'): 6550.0, ('count', u'augCGP,augTMR,transMap'): nan, ('count', u'augCGP,augTM,augTMR'): 1.0, ('count', u'augCGP'): 4178.0, ('count', u'augCGP,augTM,transMap'): nan, ('count', u'augTM,augTMR,transMap'): 5839.0, ('count', u'augTM,augTMR'): 3882.0}}
```

Which are a DataFrame that looks like:

```
>>> df
genome                                Clint   Gibbon  Orangutan   Rhesus  \
      Transcript Modes
count augCGP                         2338.0   4178.0     5753.0   4239.0
      augCGP,augTM,augTMR               1.0      1.0        1.0      NaN
      augCGP,augTM,augTMR,transMap     80.0     16.0       17.0     27.0
      augCGP,augTM,transMap             8.0      NaN        3.0      3.0
      augCGP,augTMR                     1.0      NaN        NaN      1.0
      augCGP,augTMR,transMap            NaN      NaN        1.0      NaN
      augCGP,transMap                  16.0      5.0        7.0      6.0
      augTM                          2888.0   4313.0     3656.0   5114.0
      augTM,augTMR                   1441.0   3882.0     3520.0   3357.0
      augTM,augTMR,transMap          8725.0   5839.0     6567.0   6296.0
      augTM,transMap                17341.0   6828.0     6568.0  11563.0
      augTMR                         2881.0   6550.0     5952.0   4217.0
      augTMR,transMap                 144.0    187.0      284.0    145.0
      transMap                      39284.0  44285.0    46113.0  39930.0

genome                                Susie
      Transcript Modes
count augCGP                         2740.0
      augCGP,augTM,augTMR               1.0
      augCGP,augTM,augTMR,transMap     43.0
      augCGP,augTM,transMap             2.0
      augCGP,augTMR                     NaN
      augCGP,augTMR,transMap            1.0
      augCGP,transMap                  11.0
      augTM                          2894.0
      augTM,augTMR                   2789.0
      augTM,augTMR,transMap         10196.0
      augTM,transMap                10821.0
      augTMR                         5399.0
      augTMR,transMap                 353.0
      transMap                      41300.0
```

As you can see, a few of these categories have very few entries. I want to filter each row (`Transcript Modes`) such that if they represent fewer than 1% of the total for every column, they are dropped. So, my resulting dataframe would look like:

```
>>> df
genome                                Clint   Gibbon  Orangutan   Rhesus  \
      Transcript Modes
count augCGP                         2338.0   4178.0     5753.0   4239.0
      augTM                          2888.0   4313.0     3656.0   5114.0
      augTM,augTMR                   1441.0   3882.0     3520.0   3357.0
      augTM,augTMR,transMap          8725.0   5839.0     6567.0   6296.0
      augTM,transMap                17341.0   6828.0     6568.0  11563.0
      augTMR                         2881.0   6550.0     5952.0   4217.0
      transMap                      39284.0  44285.0    46113.0  39930.0

genome                                Susie
      Transcript Modes
count augCGP                         2740.0
      augTM                          2894.0
      augTM,augTMR                   2789.0
      augTM,augTMR,transMap         10196.0
      augTM,transMap                10821.0
      augTMR                         5399.0
      transMap                      41300.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
row_sum = df.sum(axis=1)
total_sum = row_sum.sum()
print(df.loc[row_sum/total_sum > 0.01])
```

yields

```
                               Clint   Gibbon  Orangutan   Rhesus    Susie
count augCGP                  2338.0   4178.0     5753.0   4239.0   2740.0
      augTM                   2888.0   4313.0     3656.0   5114.0   2894.0
      augTM,augTMR            1441.0   3882.0     3520.0   3357.0   2789.0
      augTM,augTMR,transMap   8725.0   5839.0     6567.0   6296.0  10196.0
      augTM,transMap         17341.0   6828.0     6568.0  11563.0  10821.0
      augTMR                  2881.0   6550.0     5952.0   4217.0   5399.0
      transMap               39284.0  44285.0    46113.0  39930.0  41300.0
```